# How to check if function execution is allowed in current context?

Tags: c#, reflection, system.reflection

I use shared class in my project, so i want to check whether i can use `Assemby.GetCallingAssembly()` **without try/catch** (big perfomance loss), because on one platform this method is not allowed, so i'm getting access exception
  `Access Exception: GetCallingAssembly is not allowed in given context...`.

Example of usage:

```cs
if (!isClient)
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(s.Replace("ServerPackage", "foxrp"), JSONsettings);
else return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(s, JSONsettings);
```

Where `isClient` depends of CallingAssembly name, but on client i can't call this method due Access Exception.

Comment: Well, how often are you calling it? Couldn't you optimize by checking it once, and relying on the fact that you got an error or not afterwards? In what context does it throw the said exception?

Comment: @Icepickle i call it pretty often, like 1-60 times per second. Good idea is to check it once, but i don't know, how to do it correctly in static class.
What did you mean by "context"? I can't check it because of access exception.

Comment: well, I am wondering on which platform you are getting that Access Exception. Calling it that often really sounds curious, to what do you want to default it? A static class can just have a static private lazy property, I am assuming your executing assembly doesn't change ;) Any chance you can share a short example of the code that calls this thing?

Comment: @Icepickle I know on some platforms, like iOS, you can't use Reflection.Emit(). Didn't think GetExecutingAssembly() was a problem, though.

Comment: Hm, i don't even know how to explain that. Im using it with Rage MP, it is platform for custom server for game GTA 5. So i need to sync some shared data between client and server, but parsing this data is different on client and server (sounds crazy, but seems like this is only way). And parisng method placed in shared project, and i don't want to make two different methods for this.

Comment: Seems like i've solved this by creating static constructor, btw don't know, how safe is solution.

Comment: Well, your server won't ever change it location, I am assuming, to know more, you should really share some of the code? I guess the changes also gave you a bit of a performance boost ;)